# Call out Data from a JSON array using Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying to spit out some specific data from a JSON array using Ajax but this has been abortive, I was successful with single entry but now i need to iterate through the loops finding it slightly clumsy. I have a JSON file called result.json and needs to call some data from the JSON file

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "Content-Range": {
        "ResultsRange": [{
            "first": "1",
            "last": "2",
            "max": "2"
        }]
    },
    "data": {
        "Results": [{
            "SeriesID": "1",
            "EventNumber": "1",
            "RunId": "189",
            "FinishPosition": "184",
            "GenderPosition": "163",
            "EventDate": "2008-03-29",
            "AthleteID": "600",
            "RunTime": "00:24:39",
            "PB": "0",
            "Points": "88",
            "AgeGrading": "0.523326572008114",
            "AgeCategory": "SM25-29",
            "FirstTimer": "0",
            "GenuinePB": "0",
            "Updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "HandicapRunTime": null,
            "Assisted": null
        }, {
            "SeriesID": "1",
            "EventNumber": "1",
            "RunId": "62",
            "FinishPosition": "32",
            "GenderPosition": "29",
            "EventDate": "2005-12-03",
            "AthleteID": "600",
            "RunTime": "00:21:10",
            "PB": "1",
            "Points": "222",
            "AgeGrading": "0.609448818897638",
            "AgeCategory": "SM25-29",
            "FirstTimer": "1",
            "GenuinePB": "0",
            "Updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "HandicapRunTime": null,
            "Assisted": null
        }]
    },
    "links": [{
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "\"/v1/results?athleteId=600&offset=0&limit=100\""
    }, {
        "rel": "first",
        "href": "\"/v1/results?athleteId=600&offset=0&limit=100\""
    }, {
        "rel": "last",
        "href": "\"/v1/results?athleteId=600&offset=0&limit=100\""
    }],
    "timestamp": 1456572472,
    "originalQryTime": 1456572472
}
```

The ajax call is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("disabled");
        $.ajax({
            url: "result.json",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[Results].length; i++) {
                    returnData += '<div style="border:2px solid black; margin-top:45px;">' + '<label>' + 'Events Name: ' + '</label>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data[Results][i]["EventNumber"] + '<br><br>' + '</div>'
                }
                $("div#athlete-results").html(returnData);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML Markup is below

```
<body> 
   <div class="container" id="athlete-results"> 

   </div>
</body>
```

Can anybody help me out to iterate correctly over the loop ant spit out some needed data like EventNumber, RunId, FinishPosition and so on for each results

Comment: You are doing it right except not defining `returnData` What else you want? you want us to optimize it?

Comment: when you say defining returnData what do you mean?. I know the flow is right but i just want the iteration to spit out right values

Comment: Where was `returnData` declared? If it was not declared, then it would throw error.